# Zooming editor window android studio

Tags: android-studio

This may seem like a silly question but does anyone know how to zoom in/out of the editor window in android studio? I have actually researched it before people give me minus marks. Ctrl+ and  Ctrl- seem to fold and unfold methods, there is no zoom control in the view drop-down and all the googleing ive done has referred my to zoom the control feature of a WebView. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

In Preferences > Editor, there's an option "Change font size (Zoom) with Command+Mouse Wheel". (I'm on MacOS; on other platforms it might be control+mouse wheel).

You can also go into Preferences > Keymap > Editor Actions > Decrease Font Size/Increase Font Size/Reset Font Size and bind some keys to those commands.

IntelliJ and Android Studio have decent built-in search for finding application functions. In the preferences dialog, you can just start typing to do search (you can just start typing from a lot of places in the UI to begin a search); there's also a search box.

There's a key binding for searching actions by name; on MacOS it's command-shift-A. That's a super-handy feature.

Comment: +1 `There's a key binding for searching actions by name; on MacOS it's command-shift-A. That's a super-handy feature.` on windows it's `ctrl+shift+a`

Comment: How to get it back to the default size?

Comment: On MacOS there is a slight bug where if you have this option enabled, if you press command after a trackpad scroll, it will change the font size until the scroll settles. It is annoying and I have it disabled for this reason.

Answer (score 240):

Modify the settings of the android studio as shown below

Step 1: Open **Android Studio** and Go to **File**

Step 2: Open **Settings**

Step 3: Click on **Editor**

Step 4: Click **General**

Step 5:  Check **Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel** (as shown in below snapshot)

[image]

Comment: thanks bro you save my time but this just change the font of that file only where we increase font by our mouse but anyway it is very good

Comment: @yasiriqbal776: In the current version there is an option to adjust all windows. ... My question is why is the default disabled (to _not_ adjust font size via ctrl mouse wheel)? Who would be bothered by having that as an option? Youngsters with good eye sight maybe.

Answer (score 16):

When i update the android studio to the latest version now 2.0 the font changed and became bigger.

the provided solutions allow a change of font size just for the current page (opened page) if you want to change your entire font size of android studio you have to do this :

go to **Settings**>**Editor**>**Colors&Fonts**>**Font**

then click on **"save as"** and create a new profile name it "my profile" for example

[image]

and finally you can put the font of that profile, i put 12 so it was the previous version

Answer (score 10):

There is a alternative way to do zoom of my code, using View --> Enter presentation Mode

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On a 2016 Macbook air without an external mouse, do the accepted answer, and pinch on the trackpad to shrink the text, reverse pinch to enlarge.

Answer (score 5):

For MacBook Users:

To change font size:

```
Select **Android Studio** menu (which is present next to Apple icon)-->Preferences--->Editor-->Font-->Size(give size)-->ok
```

To zoom in and out in Editor:

```
Select **Android Studio** menu -->Editor-->General-->change font size (zoom) with command and mouse wheel-->ok
```